# How to intercept Mat Datepicker value before set to control

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I have an [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) in my Angular 12 app, and I want to intercept its value before it is received by its FormControl.

```
      <input
        matInput
        [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker"
        [min]="minDate"
        [max]="maxDate"
        formControlName="start"
      />
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"> </mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
```

This means, when I select (or type) a date, before the date is setted in the "start" control I want to be able to ask the user something with a popup. I know I could just create an Angular validation, but I do not want to show an error, just completely ignore the change if the user does not accept the popup.

I though about using directives, but I would still need a way to intercept the value from the datepicker. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that this kind of logic belongs in the component, not a directive. Why is it important to not change the form control for the date picker if the user hasn't accepted whatever is in the popup? I would subscribe to the value changes on the form, and use the pairwise operator to get the old and the new values of the form. If the value of the datepicker changes, then store the pairwise values in a class property, launch the popup. If the user accepts, do nothing because the form control is already updated, if the user declines, set the form control to the stored previous value.

Comment: I thought about this option too, but having to set the form with the previous value if the user cancels the change has two implications: the user will see the wrongly updated field until they hit the cancel button, and more importantly, two "change" events will be triggered, the first being invalid.

Comment: You could simply add a class property (or a form control that doesn't render) like `acceptedTerms = false`. Then, make the input invalid until whatever the popup is says is accepted. You could also hide the new date value using a pipe or something else from the input until `acceptedTerms` is true. Why does it matter if two change events are fired?

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar to intercept the change and I did it like this. I had view and model controls for that particular input and if conditions were met I would set the model. So in your case it could look something like this:

```
this.form.get('startDatePickerView').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourModal);

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    // update the startDatePickerModel if yes
  });
});
```

You could create a wrapper for this logic and reuse it

**EDIT:**

Basically the same thing that @meqwz said in the comment